# Why is my Linechart not showing endpoint data?

Tags: html, angular, chart.js

I am building an angular web app that should display data from an endpoint . I have created the service class and I got chart.js installed but the graph is showing a blank linechart even though the console is displaying the data .

could it be a bug issue or am i doing something wrong ? 
this is the component.ts class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from '../api.service';
import {Chart} from 'chart.js';
//import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transactions',
  templateUrl: './transactions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transactions.component.scss']
})
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {

  Linechart; 
  data ;

  market_price_usd ;
  time_date ;  

  constructor(private apiService : ApiService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.dailychart()
    .subscribe((data: any) =>   {
      this.data = data;
      console.log(data);

       this.market_price_usd = data.market_price_usd;
        this.time_date = data.timestamp;      
      })

        this.Linechart = new Chart ('canvas', {
          type : 'line',
          data : {
                  labels : this.time_date,
                  datasets :[
                    {
                      data : this.market_price_usd,
                      borderColor: '#3cb371',  
                      backgroundColor: "#0000FF",
                      fill : false
                    },                   
                  ]
                },
                options : {
                  legend: {
                    display: false
                  },
                  scales : {
                    xAxes: [{
                      display: true
                    }],
                    yAxes:[{
                      display: true
                    }],
                  }
                }
          });               
      };
    }
```

this is the service class : could the issues be from the endpoint that I am consuming ?

```
mport { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private httpclient : HttpClient ) { }

  public dailychart(){
       return this.httpclient.get('https://api.blockchain.info/stats') as Observable <Array<any>>

     }
}
```

This is the component.transaction.html code :

```
<div class="chart-container"  style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:70vw">    
    <canvas id="canvas">{{ Linechart }}</canvas>    
  </div>
```

I can't add pictures right now but the chart displays but without data...Just random numbers showed in the Yaxis . This is the result of the endpoint on the console :

```
timestamp: 1580991534000
market_price_usd: 9669.3
hash_rate: 114554768282.53265
total_fees_btc: 2465817153

.......
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the `transactions.component.html` code?

Comment: @cabesuon I will edit the post and add the component.html code , thanks